# Filtering through dropdwon in javascript not throwing any result after use a forEach and then filter query

Tags: javascript, vue.js, for-loop, foreach

Good day developers i'm developing this app right now being on the step of filtering elemens using dropdowns,querying a json object and comparing it with the selected element in the dropdown by that moment.
But any time i just select one element it doesn't show any result.
Here my json Object which is accessed by a getter called "getAllProducts":

```
{
   "user":null,
   "products":[
      {
         "product_name":"Chain Saw",
         "product_category":[
            {
               "categories_of_product":"Good"
            },
            {
               "categories_of_product":"Danger"
            },
            {
               "categories_of_product":"Homer"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "product_name":"Chuky",
         "product_category":[
            {
               "categories_of_product":"Danger"
            },
            {
               "categories_of_product":"Homer"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "product_name":"Glasses",
         "product_category":[
            {
               "categories_of_product":"Good"
            },
            {
               "categories_of_product":"Homer"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "product_name":"Tile",
         "product_category":[
            {
               "categories_of_product":"Horror"
            },
            {
               "categories_of_product":"Homer"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "product_name":"Mouse",
         "product_category":[
            {
               "categories_of_product":"Homer"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "product_name":"rino",
         "product_category":[
            {
               "categories_of_product":"Zoo"
            },
            {
               "categories_of_product":"Park"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "product_name":"Chain Saw",
         "product_category":[
            {
               "categories_of_product":"Homer"
            },
            {
               "categories_of_product":"Horror"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "product_name":"Chain Saw1",
         "product_category":[
            {
               "categories_of_product":"Homer"
            },
            {
               "categories_of_product":"Good"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "product_name":"Chain Saw2",
         "product_category":[
            {
               "categories_of_product":"Good"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "product_name":"rino1",
         "product_category":[
            {
               "categories_of_product":"Zoo"
            },
            {
               "categories_of_product":"Animal"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

then on my methods i declare a a function which previously aims to a v-modeled global variable which follows some tag in my html which was imported from one of the app components (all this works perfectly) .Lets say:

```
SCRIPT

data(){
 return{
     CategoriesDropDown: "",
 }
},
methods:{
 filterSearch(selectedCategory) {
      this.CategoriesDropDown = selectedCategory;
 },
}
```

Then on my final step while i try to filter all my elements atunning with this.CategoriesDropDown, it doesn't work, just on select whichever categories of my dropDown , all my products dissappear.Here i set the function that accesisng the json object comparing with the selected option in the dropdown should filter but doesn't work:

```
COMPUTED

   callProducts() {
       if (this.CategoriesDropDown) {
        return this.getAllProducts.products.forEach(categories => {
          return categories.product_category.filter(string => {
            return  string.categories_of_product.toUpperCase() === this.CategoriesDropDown.toUpperCase()
            ;
          });
        });
      } else {
        return this.getAllProducts.products;
    }
  },
```

Here when i don't select anything
[image]

Here when whichever of the items is selected
[image]

Any Advice about how can i improve this last function in order to correctly filter my products?.Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `forEach` in `this.getAllProducts.products.forEach(...)` with `filter`.

Like so:

```js
return this.getAllProducts.products.filter(categories => { // return only some products
  return categories.product_category.filter(string => {
    return  string.categories_of_product.toUpperCase() === this.CategoriesDropDown.toUpperCase()
  }).length !== 0 // check that product has selected category
});
```

Comment: the structure of my jason in order to accesss the categories is composed in that way ...i mean array, then a second array where in objects with the categories are.Setting a map gives me more error

Comment: really thanks Maxim ...that was my first attempt but without using .length!==0 boolean at the end of the function.Thanks for your help!!!!.Have a good Day!!!

Comment: This solution doesn't work and you will get all products everytime. The second filter will returned an empty array if nothing found and [] is truthy. So the first filter method will be always tested as true and will return all items.

Comment: My bad @MaximMazurok, I didn't see the .lenght !== 0

Answer (score 1):

`Array.prototype.forEach` returns `undefined`. Always!

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/forEach

So you have to re-think your code to avoid this `forEach`

```
 callProducts() {
       if (this.CategoriesDropDown) {
        return this.getAllProducts.products.filter(categories => {
          return categories.product_category.some((string => {
            return  string.categories_of_product.toUpperCase() === this.CategoriesDropDown.toUpperCase()
          })
        });
      } else {
        return this.getAllProducts.products;
    }
  }
```

Comment: really thanks for your response Romain it also works perfectly ...gonna keep it for future tasks .really thanks